# Highcharts Bug. Why does heatmap on highcharts doesn't render correctly the rectangles if not all coordinates are provided?

Tags: highcharts, heatmap

As it is written in the Title i try to render a heatmap charts using highcharts.
I added a click event to change the color of one point when it is clicked.

But not all coordinates have data. As a result the points are not rendering correctly.

if i try to click the top left rectangle from the datalabel and below the wrong point is being colored. 
Is this a bug?
Do i have to provide the whole set of coordinates in my data?
Here is a fiddle example of my problem
[error example](http://jsfiddle.net/80ju34xy/1/)

(this doesn t apply to all scenarios where you don't the whole set of coordinates in your data. for example this works [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/yte79gkc/1/))

```
$(function () {

$('#container').highcharts({

    chart: {
        type: 'heatmap',
        marginTop: 40,
        marginBottom: 80
    },


    title: {
        text: 'Sales per employee per weekday'
    },

    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Alexander', 'Marie', 'Maximilian', 'Sophia', 'Lukas', 'Maria', 'Leon', 'Anna', 'Tim', 'Laura']
    },

    yAxis: {
        categories: ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday'],
        title: null
    },

    colorAxis: {
        min: 0,
        minColor: '#FFFFFF',
        maxColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
    },

    legend: {
        align: 'right',
        layout: 'vertical',
        margin: 0,
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        y: 25,
        symbolHeight: 280
    },

    tooltip: {
        formatter: function () {
            return '<b>' + this.series.xAxis.categories[this.point.x] + '</b> sold <br><b>' +
                this.point.value + '</b> items on <br><b>' + this.series.yAxis.categories[this.point.y] + '</b>';
        }
    },
    plotOptions: {
        heatmap: {
            cursor: 'pointer',
            allowPointSelect: true,
            events: {
                click: function (event) {
                    if (event.point.shapeArgs && event.point.shapeArgs.fill == 'red') {
                        event.point.update({
                            color: null,
                        })
                    } else {
                        event.point.update({
                            color: 'red',
                        })
                    }
                }
            },
        }
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'Sales per employee',
        borderWidth: 1,
        data: [[0, 4, 67], [6, 4, 96], [7, 0, 31], [7, 1, 1], [7, 2, 82], [7, 3, 32], [7, 4, 30], [8, 0, 85], [8, 1, 97], [8, 2, 123], [8, 3, 64], [8, 4, 84], [9, 0, 47], [9, 1, 114], [9, 2, 31], [9, 3, 48], [9, 4, 91]],
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            color: '#000000'
        }
    }]

});});
```

Comment: Appears like a bug! @PawełFus

Comment: Practically, given a specific number of Data, this bug occurs not only on heatmap charts, but on other charts, too.